# UV mapping separate objects?

Tags: uv

I'm in 2.79 right now, (2.80 gets tired and crashes when I texture) but enough rambling, when I try to UV map separate objects the islands overlap. I'm keeping them separate because I don't want certain objects to be effected by the Subsurface modifier. I've added a picture so you can get a better idea of what I mean[image: The circled parts are the separate objects]

Comment: so if you move the UV vertices you could correct that, no?

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for the input! but I just realized I could just UV map it all together and then separate the other parts. Thanks for your time though, really. :)